# Stubbing passport isAuthenticated with Sinon and Mocha

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, passport.js, sinon

I usually find all I want on the platform but I'm running dry these days.

Here is my problem:
I'm trying to stub passport authentication (more specifically isAuthenticated) to bypass my OAuth when testing.
This method is used as a middleware in one of my routes.
Here are some snippets

AuthUtils module

```
    module.exports.ensureAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log('Auth Success', req.session.passport.user);
        return next();
      }
      console.log('Auth Fail');
      return res.redirect('/');
   };
```

Route example:

```
router.get('/', authUtils.ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res, next) => {
 //do stuff
});
```

Unit test:

```
const app = require('../../app.js');
const authUtils = require('../../scripts/auth_utils.js');
const service = require('../../services/scenes.js');
const data = require('../fixtures/data.json');


describe.only('Scenes Unit tests', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.sandbox = sinon.createSandbox(); 
  })

  afterEach(function() {
    this.sandbox.restore();
  })

  it('should get all the scenes', function(done){
    this.sandbox.stub(authUtils, 'ensureAuthenticated').returns(true);
    this.sandbox.stub(service, 'getScenes').resolves(data.list.success);

    chai.request(app)
    .get('/api/')
    .then((res) => {
      authUtils.ensureAuthenticated.should.have.been.calledOnce;
      done();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      done(err);
    });
  });
})
```

I tried using stubs, deleting module's cache, proxyquire and basically all the SO solution that were posted but nothing works. The stub is not being called, never ever

Did someone manage to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: Stub the passport authenticate method https://techbrij.com/nodejs-sinon-stub-passport-authenticate

Comment: Thank you I finally managed to have it working, the problem was coming mostly from using arrow function instead of regular function with mocha...

Comment: @Yacine can you post a full solution as an answer?